# why does a clone method always return a pointer?

Tags: c++

I am reading some clone c++ implementation, it seems always define as

```
Clonable* clone();
```

I am wondering why always return a pointer; can I define a clone to return a Clonable object?

Comment: Not seeing context is rough, but my crystal ball tells me `Clonable` is an interface in a virtual  hierarchy. [An instance would **slice**.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing)

Comment: It's worth noting that a decent *modern* implementation of the cloneable pattern would return an `std::unique_ptr` instead of a raw pointer.

Comment: @cdhowie: not so easily with covariant return type :( ...

Comment: @Jarod42 Sure it is... why wouldn't it be?

Comment: @cdhowie: I meant that `std::unique_ptr<Derived> clone() const override` is not possible :(. You have to make trade off: `std::unique_ptr<Base> clone() const override` or `Derived* clone() const override`.

Comment: @Jarod42 Sure. The way I typically implement this is to have a protected `virtual std::unique_ptr<Base> clone_impl() const` and a public `std::unique_ptr<T> clone() const` on derived types that calls the protected method and returns a downcast pointer. It's not super-duper easy but any reasonably competent C++ developer can implement it pretty easily.

Answer (score 8):

> can I define a clone to return a `Clonable` object?

Sure. Heck, you could make a `clone()` method that returns anything you want. My guess is that the `Clonable` class is meant to be used polymorphically, and that the `clone()` method is `virtual`. Pointers (or references) are your only option for runtime polymorphism in C++. If it didn't return a pointer, you'd get [object slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing).

Comment: What about type casting? Does the client code need to be something like `auto widget = static_cast<Widget*>(dynamic_cast<ConcreteWidget*>(original->clone()))`?

Comment: Without any casting, the user will just get a `Clonable*` back. Only one cast would be needed if you want the derived type, though. You shouldn't need to double-cast things like in that example.